# How many species of regular 100-sided polygons are there?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, totient-function, combinatorial-geometry

[image][image]

I saw a resolution that showed the general case starting at $ n = 8 $. It has been found that the polygon species should be prime numbers relative to $ 100 $ and less than $ 50 $. Why should it be less than $ 50 $? And how would I make a formal generalization with demonstration for a $ n $ sided polygon?

Point: The definition of regular polygon really only takes into account equal sides and equal internal angles, does not consider whether or not there is any concavity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why should it be less than $50$?

If you take steps of $57$, that's equivalent to taking steps of $-43$ and gives the same shape as taking steps of $43$.

> And how would I make a formal generalization with demonstration for a $n$ sided polygon?

The coprimality is easy: show that if you take steps of $s$ then the number of vertices is $\frac n{\gcd(n, s)}$

The choice of only one step from $\{s, n-s\}$ is easy: generalise my example above.

The slightly tricky part is showing that these conditions are sufficient. Perhaps the best approach is to calculate the angle as a function of $s$ and $n$ and use known properties of trig functions to show that there are no coincidences.

Comment: "If you take steps of 57, that's equivalent to taking steps of −43 and gives the same shape as taking steps of 43." Could you explain this part better?

Comment: @Helen, using the diagram of $n=8$ in the question, if you take steps of $3$ then the sequence is ADGBEHCFA. If you take steps of $5 \equiv -3 \pmod 8$ then the sequence is AFCHEBGDA. It's the same shape traversed in the opposite direction. Does that make sense?